# Interpreting analysis with PCA

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, pca

The focus of this question is: **What components should I keep?**

There is a dataset that has this structure:

[image]

Each row is associated with an image in a directory.
The variable confidence is a dummy value that is always 1.

The name of the coordinates where an object is identified are: `XMin, XMax, YMin, YMax.`

The name of the image characteristics are: `IsOccluded, IsTruncated, IsGroupOf, IsDepiction, IsInside.`

So I made a correlation table, which shows below that the 4 components that correspond to the points in the image are necessary.

[image]

Then a table was made with the main components and their Explained variance ratio as shown below.

[image]

After that use PCA from sklearn and it shows the number of components and their Cumulative explained variance.

[image]

I interpret from all this that the 4 coordinates are totally necessary.

[image]

**¿How Can I demonstrate that the characteristics of the image are not relevant?**

Answer (score 1):

> the last YMin coordinate has a low percentage of Cumulative explained variance

This is wrong because the PCA gives you cumulative explained variance per principal component, not per variable of your original base.

What it tells you is that you can make a projection of the data in only 3 dimensions instead of N while still keeping 70% of the variability, while if you keep 4 dimensions you keep 80% of variability. But only after a specific change of basis (that of the PCs), not dropping some of the initial variables.

To see how important the initial variables are, you can look at the vector representation of the principal components: each of their coordinates is the amount of the corresponding initial variable that is used to make this component.

> the 4 coordinates are totally necessary

It depends on your interpretation of "necessary"

Comment: To see if I understand, when you say 3 dimensions, do you start from 0 on the charts? If you start from 0 as the first component, I would say that on the X axis, it would be 4 components and not 3.

I mean necessary because the convolutional red neural has 4 coordinates as input so you can train it with a bounding box.

Comment: Actually I have to find a way to justify that only the 4 coordinates serve me, that is the input of the convolutional neural network.